# Outputting data from JSON to Textbox C#

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I'm new to C#, so this may be a very stupid question. My program is to send an api request to a server and output the data to a TextBox. The call to the API I have handled and it receives all the information in JSON format.

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    var OTPSCODE = new TOTP("CODE");
    string API = "API KEY";
    string REQ;

    REQ = SendRequest("WEBSITE"+API+"&code="+OTPSCODE.now());

    if (REQ != null)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(REQ, "Hey there!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(REQ);

        BalanceTB.Text = // This is Where I want the output to be;
    }
}

private string SendRequest(string url)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            return client.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error while receiving data from the server:\n" + ex.Message, "Something broke.. :(", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Web API returns this:

```
{ "status" : "success",
"data" : {
"available_balance" : "0",
"pending_withdrawals" : "0.0000",
"withdrawable_balance" : "0"
 }
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to display just the numbers in JSON["status"] or JSON["withdrawable_balance"] to the textbox. Can someone help me?

Comment: You'll have to parse the json you receive in order to extract the individual elements now. Something like                                               var obj = JObject.Parse(json);                                                                var balance = (string)obj["data"]["withdrawable_balance"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't supposed to serialize a `json string` again, instead you want to deserialize it :

```
var request = "WEBSITE"+API+"&code="+OTPSCODE.now();
var json = SendRequest(request);
if (json != null)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(REQ, "Hey there!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    var response = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);

    BalanceTB.Text = string.Format("{0} or {1}",
        (string)response["status"],
        (int)response["data"]["withdrawable_balance"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank You For This. The only thing is the response["data"]["withdrawable_balance"] was a string. But thanks for all the help.